# Django templates replaced

Tags: python, django, mako

i'm at the stage of learning Django and trying to get my web app running. After getting through tutorial, I really don't like the template system (no python code allowed). Can I replace it with another, like Mako or something else ? 
Or maybe there are better web frameworks than Django , and by better i mean less built-in functions more things to customize, like my own form validation ? Maybe it's possible without messing with widgets which will put too much display logic into controller and will cause code repetition

Comment: I felt the same when I started off with Django, but if you learn it the right way, the possibilities with django are unparalleled. To answer your question, it is not a good idea to inject python code in templates, and definitely not recommended

Comment: Django is written to keep developers safe from themselves.  Being able to embed python code directly in templates might be exactly what you want to do.  Writing it off as being "not a good idea" is overly simplistic and draws attention away from the fact that your app can be written like trash throughout -- the quality of your code and its organization is entirely dependent on the decisions you make architecting it.  Django happens to make a lot of those decisions for you in a one size fits all manner.  That's fine, but it might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: you can implement and `exec` and `eval` template tags and put arbitrary code in the django templates. This is not recommended and should be avoided for the reasons given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django templates have a good philosophy. Don't put code in them. If you can freely code there, it ends up like an anarchy (if you've ever coded PHP, you know what i'm talking about).

Said that, if you want to switch, I recommend you to use [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/). Here's a great post by @dcramer: http://justcramer.com/2008/03/29/using-jinja-with-django/

There are projects built to support it, like this one: https://github.com/niwibe/django-jinja